# How to convert an InfoPath web form to a pdf without programming

Tags: pdf, infopath

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Easy take a look at this blog: http://www.novapdf.com/kb/converting-infopath-forms-to-pdf-with-novapdf-114.html

Answer (score 1):

I programmed it. Seems like there are 3 options:

1) Run on a client. Install InfoPath and Acrobat/Primo/Etc. Print to PDF.

2) Repeat #1 on the server, using Office Automation APIs

3) If you have MOSS 2007 Enterprise licenses, and Your InfoPath form can be browser-published, you can use a server-based API in forms server to convert to XPS. It's not PDF but it may work.

4) Do what I did (not recommended). Use the InfoPath XSLT to convert the InfoPath XML to HTML. Fix the resultant HTML (It contains nonstandard controls & extensions). Use a tool like mentioned above to convert to HTML.

Good Luck.